# Create an xml page in shopify

Tags: xml, shopify

I need to create a simple and clean xml file and load it onto my shopify site.

What I would like is to have something like this:

http://www.wine-searcher.com/datafeed.xml

Loaded onto something like mydomain.myshopify.com/feed.xml

Any assistance on how I could do this would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make your own feed like that on Shopify. You have to use an external subdomain and your own server.

Comment: Thanks mate - racked my brain for hours on this, clearly can't be done.  Have set it up externally.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The Mulwi Feeds Shopify app can generate this file on the Shopify server based on the products you have already entered.

https://apps.shopify.com/omega-shopping-feeds